# Call to a member function getSerie() on null ( TYPO3)

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

When we access this page,and it shown an error message(call to a member function on null). This error is occur after version change. (version changed to 9 to 11). But this page is correctly working in TYPO3 version 9.

[[Click here][image: 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9RZz.png)
[[image2][image: 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyAsN.png) - When we debug the data is shown null value, but the value present in database. The code is properly working in TYPO3 version 9.
Please anyone know about this please help.

We think the issue happens due to mapping. This is method used in  version 11.

```php
`\Abavo\SitePackage\Domain\Model\FacetSelection::class => [
        'tableName' => 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_facet_selection',
        'properties' => [
            'uid' => [
                'fieldName' => 'uid'
            ],
            'pid' => [
                'fieldName' => 'pid'
            ],
            'identifier' => [
                'fieldName' => 'identifier'
            ],
            'trailer' => [
                'fieldName' => 'trailer'
            ],
            'type' => [
                'fieldName' => 'type'
            ],
            'items' => [
                'fieldName' => 'items'
            ],
            'additionalTerms' => [
                'fieldName' => 'additional_terms'
            ],
            'fin' => [
                'fieldName' => 'fin'
            ],
            'fairNumber' => [
                'fieldName' => 'fair_number'
            ],
            'sold' => [
                'fieldName' => 'sold'
            ],
            'valid' => [
                'fieldName' => 'valid'
            ],
            'datetime' => [
                'fieldName' => 'datetime'
            ],
            'comment' => [
                'fieldName' => 'comment'
            ],
            'create_user' => [
                'fieldName' => 'createUser'
            ],
            'version' => [
                'fieldName' => 'version'
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Looks like getTrailer() is null in one of the records. So, check the data and add a failsafe for it. Additionally, the mappings are not necessary, are this is the default.

Comment: ok, but the same code is working on typo3 version 9, This issue occur after the version conversion.